# how to remove the square shape border when using label tag inside an input

Tags: html, css, reactjs, upload, bootstrap-5

I need to put profile icon along with a edit icon to upload an image. i've used the following html and css to achieve this, tried adding the inline style like border:none, outline:none to the label tag, input tag, the div tag containing the input and label tag but the border is still visible.

[image]

```
<div className="avatar-edit" >
 <input type='file' id="imageUpload"  accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" onChange={handleFileChange}/>
        <label htmlFor="imageUpload" ><img src={camera} /></label>
        
    </div>

  .avatar-upload .avatar-edit {
    position: absolute;
    right: 12px;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 10px;
  }
  .avatar-upload .avatar-edit input {
    display: none;
  }
  .avatar-upload .avatar-edit input + label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: normal;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }
  .avatar-upload .avatar-edit input + label:hover {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border-color: #d6d6d6;
  }
  .avatar-upload .avatar-edit input + label:after {
    content: "\f040";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #757575;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .avatar-upload .avatar-preview {
    width: 192px;
    height: 192px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 6px solid #F8F8F8;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  .avatar-upload .avatar-preview > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of this issue.

Comment: @CBroe I'm using the code from here https://codepen.io/master/pen/pMgXqO  with some modifications on it. As you can see the small square appears in this too.

Comment: Only square I see there, is coming from the ::after pseudo element on the label - which _is_ a square, because the fontawesome font to have it display a "pen" icon instead, appears to not have been embedded in the first place.

Comment: Do you perhaps simply want to _remove_ the ::after element of the label, because you have have inserted an image for your camera icon already?